# Как убрать повторяющееся строки в txt ?

Tags: php

Доброго времени. Такой вопрос :
У меня имеется txt. Внутри есть вот это

> `gamer_kingofrap@mail.ru,
> gamer_kingofrap@mail.ru,
> app@cgi-bin.ru,
> my@cgi-bin.ru,
> my@cgi-bin.ru,
> my@cgi-bin.ru,
> my@cgi-bin.ru,
> walushakiska1.75@mail.ru,
> walushakiska1.75@mail.ru,
> ehazanova@bk.ru,
> ehazanova@bk.ru,
> sytnik2007@mail.ru,
> sytnik2007@mail.ru,
> 231969-69@mail.ru,
> 231969-69@mail.ru,
> gamer_kingofrap@mail.ru,
> gamer_kingofrap@mail.ru,
> gamer_kingofrap@mail.ru,`

Как убрать повторения? Буду благодарен даже за подсказку.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$array = file('file.txt');

$array = array_unique($array);
```

Comment: Я так и сделал.

Answer (score 5):

Попробуйте (на юниксе)

```
sort -u in.txt >out.txt
```

PS: базу данных для спама собираете?

Comment: > PS: базу данных для спама собираете?

завидуете? :D

Comment: @lampa: спамерам? только тем, до которых не могу дотянуться, остальным нет.

Comment: @VladD man uniq

Comment: @alexlz: `man sort` :) `sort -u` == `sort | uniq`.

Comment: @VladD это, конечно, гипотеза, но. В вопросе адреса сгруппированы. uniq с задачей справится. sort -u -- тем более, но строчки результата переставит. Насколько это приемлемо, я сказать не могу.

Comment: @alexlz: если бы ТС сформулировал задачу более подробно, можно было бы выяснить. Подождём комментариев.

Comment: А если у меня windows? и стоит php? шо делать?

Comment: Задача была для пыхыпы)всёравно всем спасибо.